# How should refer to data validation that happens mid-process?

Tags: error-message

I'm developing some guidelines and I can't work out what to call the type of data validation that takes place as the user enters data. i.e. an error message appears as soon as the field is unfocused.

- In-line data validation?
- In-situ data validation?
- Real-time data validation?

Is there a conventional way of referring to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The A List Apart article [Inline Validation in Web Forms](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/inline-validation-in-web-forms/) is one of the better posts on this topic and uses a couple of terms to describe this.

They called it "After" validation, which occurs "on blur".

> AFTER
>   In this version of the form, we displayed a validation message (success or error), after the user indicated that she was done answering a question by moving on to the next one. (This is validating “on blur” in technical speak.)

If you're talking to technical people it's probably just best to call it **"On Blur" validation** and clarify what that means, a la:

> This instance uses On Blur validation (the field is validated after focus leaves the field)

I would only call it "real time" when the field is validated *constantly*, when the user is still in the field, or "While" as the A List Apart post calls it:

> WHILE
>   In this variation, we displayed (and updated) a validation message while the user answered each question. (That is, “on key press.”)

Answer (score 0):

On technical note - to circumvent the issue of the user being annoyed by validation happening while they are still working, establish user intent via a timer. Example in jQuery:

```
jQuery( element ).keyup( function( event ) {

 /* User just entered something, start timer over if it exists */
 clearTimeout( itent_delay );

 /* Schedule your validation function to be initiated in 1.6 seconds */
 itent_delay = setTimeout( function () {
  validate_field( element );
 }, 1600 );

});dadsf
```

Depending on the type of information being entered, you may want to use a different intent interval.  For instance, for a password field, you could make it instant so the user is immediately notified regardless the validity/strength of their password.

On the other hand, for an e-mail field, using a 1.5-2 second intent interval is appropriate, in my opinion.